# Python - Converting String to Integer for boundary inputs

Tags: python, string, integer, type-conversion, boundary

I've been working on trying to get boundary inputs working in a small game of mine.

At first I got this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1402, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/ppppwn3d/workspace/Python/JailBreakBob/JailBreakBob.py", line 173, in     buttonclick_gamescreen
    if entryx > 10 or entryx < -10 or entryy > 10 or entryy < -10 :
TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()
```

So I realised that I had to convert the string I got from the entry widget into an integer, I looked up the code for doing on both stackoverflow and elsewhere on the web but it doesn't seem to be working.

I've tried both:

```
int (e1.get())
int (e2.get())
```

and

```
int (entryx)
int (entryy)
```

within

```
while pressed == 8 :
    int (e1.get())
    int (e2.get())
    entryx = e1.get()
    entryy = e2.get()
    answerx = answerlistx[randomimage]
    answery = answerlisty[randomimage]

    if entryx == answerx and entryy == answery:
        canvas.delete(images)
        randomimage = random.randrange(0,49+1)
        scorecounter = scorecounter + 1
        game = PhotoImage(file=imagelist[randomimage])
        images = canvas.create_image(30, 65, image = game, anchor = NW)
        e1.delete(0, END)   
        e2.delete(0, END)
        pressed = ''
    if entryx > 10 or entryx < -10 or entryy > 10 or entryy < -10 :
        wrong = canvas.create_image(30, 65, image = outside, anchor = NW)
        e1.delete(0, END)   
        e2.delete(0, END)
        pressed = ''
    else:
        wrong = canvas.create_image(30, 65, image = incorrect, anchor = NW)
        e1.delete(0, END)   
        e2.delete(0, END)
        pressed = ''
```

Without any luck. This was from following what I've read so far but I'm still getting the same error from above. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This below statements:

```
int (e1.get())   # This is actually doing nothing.
int (e2.get())
entryx = e1.get()
entryy = e2.get()
```

doesn't assign the integer value to `entryx` or `entryy`. Perhaps you wanted something like this:

```
entryx = int (e1.get())
entryy = int (e2.get())
```

Answer (score 1):

Lines `int (e1.get())` and `int (e2.get())` do actually nothing. Instead you should convert `e1.get()` and `e2.get()` to `int` while assigning them to `entryx` and `entryy`:

```
entryx = int(e1.get())
entryy = int(e2.get())
```

`int()` doesn't convert items in place:

```
>>> s = "100"
>>> int(s)
100
>>> s
'100'
>>> type(s)
<type 'str'>
```