# TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()

Tags: python, tkinter

Need help with this error.

my code:

```
from tkinter import *

def shouldIEat():

    if calories.get() < 1523 :
     answer.set("Eat food as soon as possible")

    elif calories.get() > 1828 :
     answer.set("Stop eating")

    else:
     answer.set("You can eat something, but don't go over 1828")

window = Tk()

answer = StringVar()
calories = IntVar()



calories.set(0)


caloriesLabel = Label(window, text = "How many calories have you consumed?")
caloriesLabel.grid( row = 1)

calories = Entry(width = 10)
calories.grid (row = 1, column = 1)

eatButton = Button(window, text = "Should I eat?" , command=shouldIEat).grid( row = 2 , column = 1)
quitButton = Button(window, text = "Quit" ,  command=window.quit).grid( row = 2 , column = 2)

window.mainloop()
```

My error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1487, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:/My Documents/School/Scripting Lang/Project", line 8, in shouldIEat
    if calories.get() < 1523 :
TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()
```

Comment: What is that code supposed to do? Where are you using `answer` or the `IntVar()` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18170406/python-converting-string-to-integer-for-boundary-inputs

Comment: @ChrisMagnussen: explicit conversion to `int` isn't actually required here, the `IntVar` object does the conversion for you.

Answer (score 2):

Your code sets up `calories` as a Tkinter IntVar, but then it clobbers it by creating an Entry with the same name. You need to give the Entry a different name, and then attach the `calories` IntVar using the `textvariable` argument in the Entry constructor.

Also, you never created a widget to display the answer.

```
from tkinter import *

def shouldIEat():
    if calories.get() < 1523 :
        answer.set("Eat food as soon as possible")
    elif calories.get() > 1828 :
        answer.set("Stop eating")
    else:
        answer.set("You can eat something, but don't go over 1828")

window = Tk()

answer = StringVar()
calories = IntVar()

calories.set(0)
#answer.set('')

caloriesLabel = Label(window, text = "How many calories have you consumed?")
caloriesLabel.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

caloriesEntry = Entry(width = 10, textvariable=calories)
caloriesEntry.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

Button(window, text = "Should I eat?", command=shouldIEat).grid(row = 2, column = 1)
Button(window, text = "Quit" , command=window.quit).grid(row = 2, column = 2)

answerLabel = Label(window, textvariable=answer)
answerLabel.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

window.mainloop()
```

We don't really need to initialise `answer`, but it is neater to do so. And you could use it to display some simple instructions, if you want.

There's another minor problem with your code that I should mention.

```
eatButton = Button(window, text = "Should I eat?" , command=shouldIEat).grid( row = 2 , column = 1)
```

This creates a `Button` object and then calls its `.grid()` method. That's fine, but the `.grid()` method returns `None`, it does **not** return the `Button` object, so saving that return value to `eatButton` is pointless. You don't need to keep a reference to that button for this program, which is why I changed it to

```
Button(window, text = "Should I eat?", command=shouldIEat).grid(row = 2, column = 1)
```

in my version. But when you *do* need to keep a reference to the widget you should construct it on one line and then apply the `.grid()` (or `.pack()`) method on a separate line, like you did with `caloriesLabel`.

BTW, in Python, names of the form `calories_label` are preferred over `caloriesLabel`. See [PEP-008](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for further details.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the TypeError, you are comparing a string with an integer.

Cast your string to an integer before doing your comparison.